# Editable textfield

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this query and i need to make a php code where to integrate this query in order to display Students Name, Surname, Date (of exam) and a textfield for each student where the teacher to input the grade with wich each student has been valuated and this textfield must be editable. I stuck on the textfield part because i'm noot very familiar with php. In this query i display the grade field but its not a textfield to input data it has a value of 0 i want to change this part!

```
SELECT student.Name, student.Surname, subject.Date, exam.Grade
FROM student
INNER JOIN assignment ON assignment.ID_Student=student.ID_Student
INNER JOIN exam ON assignment.ID_Student=exam.ID_Student
INNER JOIN subject ON exam.ID_Subject=subject.ID_Subject
WHERE ((subject.ID_Subject)=1 AND ((sem)>=75) AND ((lab)=1))
```

Comment: You'll need to add your PHP code to the question as well, please. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking how to make an online form in PHP to do controlled database updates?  This is actually pretty involved ... I'd recommend these books:  [Programming PHP](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-PHP-Kevin-Tatroe/dp/1449392776/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1367858109&sr=8-1&keywords=php+oreilly) and [Learning PHP, MySQL, Javascript, and CSS](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-MySQL-JavaScript-Step---Step/dp/1449319262/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1367858109&sr=8-3&keywords=php+oreilly)

Comment: i said that i am not familiar with php, could u please write a piece of code where you create a textfield for each student, because i created one but it has two textfields one for student id and one for grade, but i don't want it that way, i want it to be a textfield after each name of student in table format. How can i connect this textfield with my query?

Comment: This isn't a 'write it for you' site.  Writing that code takes a while and how you write it depends on your tools at hand.  Thus why I suggested two books that should help you become more familiar with PHP.

Comment: thank you but i can't buy them. Is there another way to download for free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use php to output html contents. In its simplest way it will look the way I have written below. Draw database information and store that in a variable say `students` and then iterate through it to display in the way you desire including textboxes, forms or whatever you wish.

```
<?php
$students //array that contains all the student information from the database
echo "<html>";
echo "<form action=\"index.php\">";
foreach( $students as $student )
{
    echo "Name: {$student['name']}......";
    echo "Grade: <input type=\"text\" name=\"{$student['name']}\"value={$student['grade']}>";
    echo "</br> </hr>";
}
    echo "input type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"";
echo "</form>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

I can't write a detailed code for you. This should be helpful enough I suppose.

Comment: thank you , i have got the idea. Just a last thing, how does it gets the student name from my database echo "Name: {$student['name']}? i think i need to put my query somewhere to display the students that can give an exam ( because not all students can do it) my query is ok because it does this, but where can i put it inside this code?

Comment: At the very beginning of the code, you must construct the query string, connect to the database using php mysqli function. Then execute the query. Array containing the students information will be returned. Store this array in a $students variable. Iterate through all the students and generate the required html markup.

Answer (score 0):

By what I understood from your question I guess simply using a "text" input box with the "value" of the grade should easily work.

```
<input type="text" value="grade"/>
```

The `grade` must be replaced by `exam.Grade` through your template engine in php or by what ever way you wish to parse your template.

Comment: but how can i integrate this in order to be a field after each student name in a table format foer example

Comment: Student NameSurname Date        Grade                                             Johny   Deep        06.05.2013  [textfield to input grade]